# Using python's core.Clock.GetTime() method within a while loop: timing distortions?

Tags: python, time, while-loop, sleep, psychopy

I came across an interesting issue when discussing timing precision on the psychopy forum (psychopy is a psychology software written in python). Here's the problem:

```
timer=core.Clock()#instantiate a clock
stimulus.draw()#draw stimulus
win.flip()#flip the monitor to make stimulus appear
Routine = True
While Routine:
    key_press = event.getKeys(keyList=["f", "j"])#check keyboard's buffer
    if len(key_press) > 0:#keypress detected!
       RT = timer.getTime()#record response time
       Routine = False
```

I've been told that calling getTime() within a while loop can be dangerous : "A very tight loop hogs all the CPU time to itself, choking other processes, which might just eventually break in and seize control for quite a while to get through a backlog, completely mucking up your timing. On each iteration, call something like time.sleep(0.001) to yield time to other processes." I don't see why it would be. Can somebody shed light on this programming issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I stop a while loop after n amount of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293269/how-would-i-stop-a-while-loop-after-n-amount-of-time)

Answer (score 1):

I'll have a go at answering, based off the discussion found at [How would I stop a while loop after n amount of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293269/how-would-i-stop-a-while-loop-after-n-amount-of-time/13293360), and specifically Anthony's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44723559/8763097

`while True:` loops tend to hog the CPU processes in what, I think, is termed: [Busy Waiting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)

> Busy-waiting, busy-looping or spinning is a technique in which a
>   process repeatedly checks to see if a condition is true, such as
>   whether keyboard input or a lock is available.
>
> Busy-waiting itself can be made much less wasteful by using a delay
>   function (e.g., sleep()) found in most operating systems. This puts a
>   thread to sleep for a specified time, during which the thread will
>   waste no CPU time. If the loop is checking something simple then it
>   will spend most of its time asleep and will waste very little CPU
>   time.

So your while loop is spending a lot of time checking the if statement value of `len(key_press)` over and over and over. Adding a `sleep()`routine will allow the While loop to pause, whereby other processes can take place.

This may be why you report inconsistencies in your time function - the function [.core.getTime()](http://www.psychopy.org/api/core.html#psychopy.core.Clock) is not a core python function. It's part of the core of your psychopy package, and it doesn't look like a process clock...it looks like a basic clock timer. As such, the timer may be influenced by the While loop's CPU hogging. Without knowing any more about your package's clock handling, however, this is simply a guess.

Perhaps to avoid this problem, consider using `time.perf_counter()` with a sleep function as this will include any `sleep()` time within the count.

EDIT 1: Perhaps one solution is to work with the MS VC++ Runtime library, which is couched within Python's core.

```
import msvcrt
import time

print("GO")
start = time.perf_counter()
while True:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print(end-start)
        break
```

The library should be able to handle the command to wait for a keyboard press before moving to the next step in the loop. Does it solve the problem? Not quite. Can the problem really be solved? I'm not sure...

Comment: The idea here was to check the keyboard's buffer at a very high sampling rate. Adding a time.sleep() of say 1ms to each while loop iteration is dangerous, as the smallest interval one may sleep on a windows machine is 12-13ms (see doc). In addition, time.sleep() may vary by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activities in the system. You are correct that core.getTime() is not a python core function.   The clock is based on windll.Kernel32.QueryPerformanceFrequency(byref(_qpfreq)) (for a windows machine)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand the problem a lot better now. Short of running your program on a linux machine and using a real time kernel (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep) that can take you closer to 1ms, you could also try working with msvcrt (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365473/python-windows-msvcrt-getch-only-detects-every-3rd-keypress) or even a PyGame handler (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. To further clarify: I don't know if there is a timing issue.  I checked CPU usage during the while loop (without any keypress), and I was around 60%, which looks fine. Peharps the first step would be to check if timing is distorted, and quantify the amplitude of this distortion. I think this is an interesting programming issue that may be helpful for the community.

Comment: No worries. And yes, I agree - this is an interesting little problem! Maybe someone will see this in 7 years' time and benefit from the discussion. If you're looking for a way to quantify the time discrepancies, perhaps take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133984/8763097 or maybe even https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771965/8763097 for methods to quantify the change.